# Embeddable HTML layout editor/widgets palette

Tags: javascript, html, editor

I wasn't sure whether this would constitute something that should be put on SO, but seeing as it discusses JavaScript framework, basically, I've decided to go for it.

I am on the lookout for an **embeddable, written in JavaScript/HTML/CSS, HTML palette/layout editor**.

**Extensibility is the most important part.**

Since picture is worth a 1000 words, this is something I'd like to have:

[image]
<sub>(source: [intel.com](http://html5dev-software.intel.com/en-us/xdkdocs/app_designer/tutorials_and_videos/GUID-D2DB1D53-90CF-4B53-8C10-9717EB21BAF8-low.jpg))</sub>

The purpose is to, well, embed it in a Node.js + Browser development tool (IDE of sorts).

Any suggestions are welcome.

So far I've got the usual WYSIWYG editors/text editors (CodeMirror, Ace, TinyMCE) which clearly are not suitable, as they provide coding interface, whereas I am looking for more of a graphical one.

Additionally, XDK was given a look (which is where the screenshot is from), but it doesn't seem as if it can be a) customized and b) embedded

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [CK Editor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [MXGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html)